# D3D9 Windowed Mode Multi-monitor

Tags: c#, direct3d, slimdx, direct3d9, multiple-monitors

I have just started looking into D3D9 using SlimDX.

I have a device created off the primary display adapter and device.present only flips the backbuffer onto the primary monitor. When the window is moved to the secondary display, the surface is no longer updated. That is expected.

What I'm trying to do though, is that if the window is moved across to the secondary display (fully across to secondary display or partially, occupying both primary and secondary displays), the same rendered image gets presented.

What do I need to do to achieve this (someone suggested CreateAdditionalSwapChain [here](http://tape-worm.net/?p=229) and [here](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/vmr9-several-devices-help-27215762.html), but I'm not getting the bigger picture of how this could work)?

I only intend to support multi-head cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason it wasn't showing on the secondary screen.

I (or more appropriately, the sample code) had PresentFlags.DeviceClip set when creating the D3D9 device. Removing it allows it to work across the screens.